# Справа на странице сайте появилась вертикальная полоса

Tags: html, css, grid

"Исследуя элемент", заметила в  во 2-ом  стоит margin-right, кот-й не получается убрать.  вылезает за сетку. Как это исправить?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Michroma&display=swap');
body {
  font-family: Michroma, serif;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #0b00a8 0%, #141414 100%);
}

.nav-link {
  color: aquamarine;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
  color: blueviolet;
}

.navbar-brand>img {
  height: 2em;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  background: blueviolet;
}

.sidebar {
  color: aquamarine;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, #0b00a8 0%, #141414 100%);
}

.card {
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, #0b00a8 0%, #141414 100%);
  color: aquamarine;
}

.card a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="source/style/mycss.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="source/file/main-icon.png" alt="Иконка"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="pricing.html">Pricing</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <section>
    <div class="conteiner-fluid mt-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mt-4">
              <div class="card">
                <a href="#"><img src="source/image/laptop.png" class="card-img-top" alt="Laptop"></a>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#">Laptops</a></h5>
                  <p class="card-text"><a href="#">
                                        Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                                            the bulk of the card's content.
                                    </a></p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mt-4">
              <div class="card">
                <img src="source/image/vr.png" class="card-img-top" alt="Vr">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">VR</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mt-4">
              <div class="card">
                <img src="source/image/gaming pc.png" class="card-img-top" alt="gaming">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">gaming pc</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mt-4">
              <div class="card">
                <img src="source/image/controller.png" class="card-img-top" alt="controller">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">controller</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mt-4">
              <div class="card">
                <img src="source/image/acc.png" class="card-img-top" alt="acc">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">acc</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mt-4">
              <div class="card">
                <img src="source/image/cpu.png" class="card-img-top" alt="cpu">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">cpu</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mt-4">
              <div class="card">
                <img src="source/image/gpu.png" class="card-img-top" alt="gru">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">gru</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mt-4">
              <div class="card">
                <img src="source/image/other.png" class="card-img-top" alt="other">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">other</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 sidebar my-4">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit, numquam alias architecto veritatis deleniti ipsam magni laborum distinctio nisi velit! <a href="#">Learn more >>></a></p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-12 sidebar my-4">
              <p> Fugit, numquam alias architecto veritatis deleniti ipsam magni laborum distinctio nisi velit! <a href="#">Learn more >>></a></p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-12 sidebar my-4">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit, numquam alias architecto veritatis deleniti ipsam magni laborum distinctio nisi velit! <a href="#">Learn more >>></a></p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-12 sidebar my-4">
              <p>Numquam alias architecto veritatis deleniti ipsam magni laborum distinctio nisi velit! <a href="#">Learn more >>></a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </section>

  <footer>

  </footer>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: исправьте `conteiner-fluid` на `container-fluid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Michroma&display=swap');
body {
  font-family: Michroma, serif;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #0b00a8 0%, #141414 100%);
  max-width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nav-link {
  color: aquamarine;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
  color: blueviolet;
}

.navbar-brand>img {
  height: 2em;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  background: blueviolet;
}

.sidebar {
  color: aquamarine;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, #0b00a8 0%, #141414 100%);
}

.card {
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, #0b00a8 0%, #141414 100%);
  color: aquamarine;
}

.card a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="source/style/mycss.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="source/file/main-icon.png" alt="Иконка"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="pricing.html">Pricing</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <section>
    <div class="conteiner-fluid mt-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mt-4">
              <div class="card">
                <a href="#"><img src="source/image/laptop.png" class="card-img-top" alt="Laptop"></a>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#">Laptops</a></h5>
                  <p class="card-text"><a href="#">
                                        Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                                            the bulk of the card's content.
                                    </a></p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mt-4">
              <div class="card">
                <img src="source/image/vr.png" class="card-img-top" alt="Vr">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">VR</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mt-4">
              <div class="card">
                <img src="source/image/gaming pc.png" class="card-img-top" alt="gaming">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">gaming pc</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mt-4">
              <div class="card">
                <img src="source/image/controller.png" class="card-img-top" alt="controller">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">controller</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mt-4">
              <div class="card">
                <img src="source/image/acc.png" class="card-img-top" alt="acc">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">acc</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mt-4">
              <div class="card">
                <img src="source/image/cpu.png" class="card-img-top" alt="cpu">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">cpu</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mt-4">
              <div class="card">
                <img src="source/image/gpu.png" class="card-img-top" alt="gru">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">gru</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mt-4">
              <div class="card">
                <img src="source/image/other.png" class="card-img-top" alt="other">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">other</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 sidebar my-4">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit, numquam alias architecto veritatis deleniti ipsam magni laborum distinctio nisi velit! <a href="#">Learn more >>></a></p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-12 sidebar my-4">
              <p> Fugit, numquam alias architecto veritatis deleniti ipsam magni laborum distinctio nisi velit! <a href="#">Learn more >>></a></p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-12 sidebar my-4">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit, numquam alias architecto veritatis deleniti ipsam magni laborum distinctio nisi velit! <a href="#">Learn more >>></a></p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-12 sidebar my-4">
              <p>Numquam alias architecto veritatis deleniti ipsam magni laborum distinctio nisi velit! <a href="#">Learn more >>></a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </section>

  <footer>

  </footer>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```